# Detecting design time in a Windows 8 Metro app?

Tags: windows-8

How do I detect if I am in design time in my Windows 8 app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick search on google before posting helped me to find the answer. I post it here anyway:

```
bool designMode = Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled;
```

[DesignMode class documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.designmode.designmodeenabled)